# Retrieve/process/show wikipedia page in IOS application

Tags: ios, wikipedia

I am going to show a mobile version of wikipedia page in my app.

The easiest way is to use UIWebView to show mobile view page, e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=White_House

However I want to make certain changes to the page:

1. Remove the search bar.
2. remove all external links in the page.

while keep all format/image/layout unchanged.

I did some search. Seems I have to retrieve all contents in json with wikipedia API and reformat everything by myself.

Any easier way?

Comment: Why don't you use the APIs? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the HTML, make "Find and replace" and remove whatever you want. (Modify the HTML itself.
After that you can load the HTML into the UIWebView.

Note: This might break when wikipedia will change it's webpage structure...

Comment: Thanks. I realized I needn't use API, but just manipulate the HTML contents.